# Bitwise and shift operands to clear a chosen hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I have been trying for a while now (and cant seem to succeed) to write a program in C++ that takes in a value (in hex) and converts any of the numbers within that number to zero. The user chooses which number starting from the left (LSB). I would like to be able to accomplish this task by only using bitwise functions and the shift operand.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int zero(int, int);

int main()
{
  int hex_num;
  int byte_num;

  cout << "Enter a hexadecimal number please: " << endl;
  cin >> hex >> hex_num;



  cout << "Which byte would you like to zero: " << endl;
  cin >> byte_num;

  cout << hex << zero(hex_num, byte_num) << endl;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

int zero(int hex_num, int byte_num)
{

  int b;
  int mask = 0x0001;

  b = hex_num & ~(mask << byte_num);


 return b;
}
```

Comment: You're only masking 1 bit. Try `0x000f` to mask four bits.

Comment: It works in some cases, but not all.

Comment: Yup, that's true. You should be able to figure it out by looking at the pattern of the cases that work.

Comment: ahhh, ok. Ill do that.

Answer (score 3):

The problems are indeed in the `zero()` function.
I don't want to give you the working code, so here are some inputs that will hopefully help you (if not, just ask):

1. Like in the comments already said, a byte has not only one bit. If you want to set one whole byte to zero you need to set 8 bits to zero (hint: look at your mask)
2. Bit shifting only shifts for one single bit NOT one byte (or 8 bits). So `(0b0011 << 1) == 0b0110` will only shift for one bit.
3. Just for the looks: `b` is unnecessary. You can use

   return hex_num & ~(mask << byte_num);

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit confusing because you used the word "number" for different meanings, so try to always make sure you are describing the question as clearly as you can.

Digit is one possible word to describe the "number" you are trying to zero. If I understand correctly you want to develop a function that takes  an integer value and zero out one of the digits in the hexadecimal representation using only bitwise operations.

To understand how you can do it you need to first understand what the Hexadecimal representation really means. Specifically what a single digit in base-16 means in base-2(binary).
In hex a single digit can represent values in range [0,15] that's the same as what 4 bits represent in binary.

( F ) <sub>h</sub> = ( 1111 ) <sub>2</sub>
( 0 ) <sub>h</sub> = ( 0000 ) <sub>2</sub>

So to zero a single digit in base-16 we need to zero 4 bits. Let's move to the implementation:

```cpp
int zero_hex_digit(int hex_val, int digit){
   return hex_val & ~(0x0F << (digit-1)*4);
}
```

The not `~` operation on the `0x0F` mask simply creates a representation where the first 4 bits are `0` and the rest is `1`. So when you wish to remove the first digit (from left to right), you just bitwise `AND` this mask with the value.

When you want to zero other digits, you need to left-shift the `0x0F` mask by multiples of 4.

Now the `(digit-1)` only serves to offset the digit parameter, so the left-most digit on hex representation starts at `1` (you can remove `-1` and represent the left-most digit as `0`).